# CSS, jQuery: How can I zoom a image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image gallery which holds lots of inline-block containers (similar to a chess field). No when I use the browser zoom strg + mouse wheel the images get scaled so that I can see more or less depending on if I zoom out or zoom in.

My question now is how I can do this directly in jQuery (maybe with a slide) without using the browser zoom function?

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to change all widths heights?

Regards

Comment: If you used some kind of a slider (vertical or horizontal) you can write a function that modifies the width/height of the inline blocks and images within. It's just a simple matter of managing the previous zoom factor and the new value. Give it a shot and post questions with the difficulties you face along the way. People won't do the implementation for you.

Comment: My question is if there is a easy way or if I have to scale directly the widths and heights. I assume second is the way to go. That was my question not more not less ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question would be *how much* do you want to zoom the images and how big they are. I'm asking because you will need to preload the images at their maximum resolution, could be slow with large images.

Assuming this is not an issue, what I would do is write my own function to animate both width and height; I think there is no more straightforward way.

Other than this, there are plenty of jQuery plugins out there: just Google them, I've found an interesting list on: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-zoom.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Will take a look at youre list. And will think about what to do with the images...

Answer (score 0):

Try also this, in compact form:

```
$('#image').mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).animate({width: "300px", height: "300px"}, 'slow');
});
$('#image').mouseout(function()
{   
    $(this).animate({width: "200px", height: "200px"}, 'slow');
});
```